Why won’t my Alienware desktop PC start up after changing the CMOS battery?
I recently replaced the CMOS battery in my Alienware desktop PC and now it will not start up at all.
I replaced the CMOS battery and started the PC without problems (Windows 10) and used it for a day or two. But now when I try and power on the PC nothing happens (normally the light behind the power button comes on when I press it and then the PC starts up).

I thought it was a power problem so checked the power cable to the PSU was working - it was.
I thought it could be a cable come loose on the motherboard (when I had swapped the CMOS battery) so checked and all cables seem attached and fine.
I though it could be the PSU so took out the PSU and attached the EVGA Detection Tool and when I turn on the PSU it starts and the fan spins up, so the PSU appears to work.
I tried replacing the “new” CMOS battery with another battery and PC still won’t start.

What else should I try? What could it be?
